# How to use char * in C

Tags: c++, c

I have main function like this:

```
void main()
{
     char *s;
     inputString(s);
     printf("%s",s);

}
```

and inputString function:

```
void inputString(char *&s)
{

    //Some code line to input a string and set s point to this string

}
```

Is there have a function auto malloc memory enough store string which inputed (I need input string in inputString function).

Comment: What's wrong in using `std::string` and `std::cin` ?

Comment: `void inputString(char *&s)` looks like C++ to me, although not very idiomatic C++.

Comment: std::string will "save" you if you don't know how to alloc/free memory...

Comment: I need input string in inputString function

Comment: Somebody changed the tags from C++ to C, to match the title, but the code is still C++. Can we just retag this as "confused-author"...?

Comment: @leduchuy89vn: Elaborate on what you're trying to do, and clarify what language you're trying to do it in, because most of us here are taking pot shots in the dark here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing C and C++ in your example.

In your case before you can use **s** it should be initialized. For example, like this:

```
void inputString(char *&s)
{
    s = strdup(xxx); // or malloc, calloc, etc.

}
```

But really, then it's better to just use plain old C:

```
char* inputString(void)
{
    char* s = strdup(xxx);
    return s;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Just 3 lines of code (put these inside `int main()` )are enough

```
std::string s;
std::cin >> s; //or getline() as desired
std::cout << s;
```

Comment: I need input string in inputString function!

Comment: @leduchuy89vn: Then put these three lines in there. They'll work pretty much everywhere (they won't work in functions that already declare another variable `s`). Note that you do need `#include <string>` and `#include <iostream>` for `std::string` and `std::cin`/`std::cout` respectively.

Answer (score 4):

If you keep using this C style approach, then no, you will have to make assumptions and allocate enough memory yourself. The C++ approach is much more superior, use std::strings and don't do manual allocations:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
void inputString(std::string& s)
{

    //Don't bother for the memory management

}
int main() 
{
     std::string s;
     inputString(s);
     std::cout << s ;
}
```

Also do note that your code is not legal C++. ***`void main()` is illegal!!!***

***Edit:*** At the time of this answer the question was tagged C++. Later the question was retagged NOT by the OP, and I don't quite agree with it...

Comment: Note that `void main` isn't even legal C.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are doing this is C and not C++.

There are two approaches, either `inputString` must allocate the memory or the caller of `inputString` must allocate the memory.

if inputString allocates the memory your function will probably look something like:

```
char* inputString(void)
{
    int len = strlen (MyInternalString) + 1;
    char* s = malloc (len);
    strncpy(s, MyInternalString, len);
    return s;
} //similar to what Rustram illustrated
```

you should also include:
void freeString(char* str)
{
    free(str);
}
as well. This makes it clear to the user that they are required to manage the memory of the returned string themselves.

Alternatively you can write inputString where the user is expected to provide the required memory. This will then look something like

```
int inputString(char* str, int maxLen) //
{
  if (maxLen >= myInternalStringLength + 1)
  {
    strncpy(str, myInternalString, maxLen)

  }
  return myInternalStringLength  + 1;
}
```

Here the user of my string can check the return code to see if the buffer that he allocated was big enough. If it was too small, then he can always realloc a bigger one

Your main now becomes:

```
int main()
{
     char *s = NULL;
     int len = inputString(s, 0);
     s = alloca(len); //allocates the memory on the stack
     len = inputstring(s, len);
     printf("%s",s);
} //no need to free the memory because the memory alloca'ed gets 
  //freed at the end of the stack frame
```

Comment: +1 for reasonable answer, -1 for relying on `strdup` which is not a standard C function, and for `void main()`. Total: 0

Answer (score 0):

```
int main()
{
    std::string s;
    inputString(s);
    printf("%s",s.c_str());  
}
```

and inputString function:

```
void inputString(std::string& s)
{
    //Some code line to input a string and set s point to this string
    std::cin >> s;
}
```